# close / unload UiLoader as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6, uiloader

I'm using a `Loader` to display a SWF. I have a button to load the SWF and I want that same button to close or hide or unload the SWF.

Here's part of my code:

```
var so:Boolean = false ;
    glossary.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, glossaire)
    function glossaire (e:MouseEvent) {
        var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
        var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("glossary.swf");
        if (so == false )
        {
            so = true ;
            myLoader1.load(url);                                    
            addChild(myLoader);
        }
        else{  
            so = false ;
            //i tried  
            myUILoader.unload(); 
            removeChild(myUILoader);
            // but my loader still appear in the stage how can remove or hide it
        }
    }
```

Comment: well i'd like to click a button to load my swf and when it's loaded if i click the same button it close the swf ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your loader is scoped to the click function, and that you are creating a new Loader every click (when really you only want to create a new loader on the first click).  Also, you seem to be confused on what your loader is called as you have references to `myLoader`, `myLoader1` and `myUILoader`.

```
//put the loader var out of the function scope here (so it persists after the function finishes). 
var myLoader:Loader;

glossary.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, glossaire);

function glossaire (e:MouseEvent){

    //instead of using the so boolean, just check if loader is null
    if (myLoader == null){
        myLoader = new Loader();
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("glossary.swf"));                                    
        addChild(myLoader);
    }else{
        myLoader.unloadAndStop(); 
        removeChild(myLoader);
        myLoader = null; //set it to null now that it's been removed, so the next time this click function runs, a new loader will be made
    }
}
```

---

If you just wanted to hide the loaded swf (instead of completely unloading it), you could do this:

```
function glossaire (e:MouseEvent){
    //create the loader and load if it hasn't been done yet
    if (myLoader == null){
        myLoader = new Loader();
        myLoader.load(new URLRequest("glossary.swf"));                                    
    }

    //the parent property of the loader will be null if it hasn't been added (or has been removed) via addChild/removeChild
    if(myLoader.parent != null){
        removeChild(myLoader);
    }else{
        addChild(myLoader);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , let me tell you an easy way to solve this issue,

Create a load complete event `Event.Complete` and listen it to a function , set a boolean from there , in your case `var so:Boolean` and use the same functionality,

```
var so:Boolean = false ;
glossary.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, glossaire)
function glossaire (e:MouseEvent) {
    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                     
    var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("glossary.swf");
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, swfload);
    if (so == false )
    {
        so = true ;
        myLoader.load(url);                                    
        addChild(myLoader);
    }
    else{  
        so = false ;
        //i tried  
        myUILoader.unload(); 
        removeChild(myUILoader);
        // but my loader still appear in the stage how can remove or hide it
    }
}

function swfload(e:Event):void
 {
   if(e.type == Complete)
   so = false;
 }
```